# replace headers of files using a different file that has the name information

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a couple of fasta files (OG000*.fas) [files](https://filebin.net/4zp0ocozwpoti8lj) that I need to rename the headers (i.e. all the values after the ">").
The tricky part is that the string that I need to replace in each header is in a separate file with the name "names" therefore I want for each of the "fas" files to find the replacement string based on a line in the "names" file.

Here is what I have done so far

```
for f in OG000*.fas; do grep ">" $f > ${f%.fas}.names; done
```

which basically wrote the headers in seperate files and using these *.names files I found the replacement strings in the "names" file

```
for f in *.names; do grep -w -Ef $f names > ${f%.names}.rep; done
```

as you can see these rep files have the following format:

> ERR3393546_DBSCAN_round2_18.faa:>ERR3393546_k127_667963_61 # 82953 # 83516 # 1 # ID=38_61;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=None;rbs_spacer=None;gc_cont=0.520
> ERR3393546_DBSCAN_round2_27.faa:>ERR3393546_k127_1356642_14 # 16672 # 17229 # 1 # ID=43_14;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=TAAAA;rbs_spacer=8bp;gc_cont=0.507
> ERR3393546_DBSCAN_round2_9.faa:>ERR3393546_k127_931034_2 # 237 # 797 # -1 # ID=148_2;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=AATAA;rbs_spacer=7bp;gc_cont=0.556
> ERR3393547_DBSCAN_round1_3.faa:>ERR3393547_k127_88473_83 # 97476 # 98036 # 1 # ID=5_83;partial=00;start_type=ATG;rbs_motif=TAA;rbs_spacer=11bp;gc_cont=0.440

where the string after the ":" is what the header looks in the original "fas" file and the string before ":" is what I would like the new header to look like

therefore the headers in the new "fas" files should look like this:

> ">ERR3393546_DBSCAN_round2_18"

> ">ERR3393546_DBSCAN_round2_27"

> ">ERR3393546_DBSCAN_round2_9"

> ">ERR3393547_DBSCAN_round1_3"

and here i am a bit stuck cause I kind of have an idea that I should use something like `while read rep file; do sed`...
but I cant wrap my head around how to do it exactly

any help is greatly appreciated

ps: I did not upload the original "names" file cause its 200MB

Comment: Please use code formatting for example input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, probably not the most elegant solution but here is what I came up with

```
sed -i 's/ .*//g' *.fas

for f in OG000*.fas; do grep ">" $f > ${f%.fas}.names; done
for f in *.names; do grep -w -Ef $f names > ${f%.names}.rep; done

sed -i 's/ .*//g' *.rep

for f in OG000*.fas; do awk -vRS="\n" -vORS="\t" '1' $f  | sed -e 's/\t>/\n>/g' > ${f}_file1; done
for f in *.rep; do awk -vRS=":" -vORS="\t" '1' $f | awk '{ $(NF+1)=$1; sub(/^[^ ]+ */,"") }1' > ${f}_file2; done

for f in *.rep_file2; do awk '
NR==FNR {vals[$1] = $2 " " $3 " " $4; next} 
!($1 in vals) {vals[$1] = "0 0 0"} 
{$(NF+1) = vals[$1]; print}
' $f ${f%rep_file2}fas_file1 | awk '{print $3,$2}' | sed -e 's/ /\n/g'     | sed -e 's/.faa//g' | sed "/DBSCAN/ s/^/>/" | sed "/.assembled/ s/^/>/" | sed "/_protein/ s/^/>/" > ${f}output; done
```